# Insert statement and State drop down not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello i am having trouble with getting my form to validate right as well as getting the insert statement to post a confirmed message/post to the table in the database.

Here is the code

```
<?php require_once('dbuser.php');?>
<?php
// if the submit button has been selected
if(isset($_POST['submit_registration'])) {
    // assign variable to each for control to capture the values
    $first = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
    $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $postal = $_POST['postal_code'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $distance = $_POST['dist'];
    //assign null values for use with the isset function to identify null fields that are missing a value
    $nofirst = null;
    $nolast = null;
    $noemail = null;
    $noaddress1 = null;
    $noaddress2 = '';
    $nocity = null;
    $nostate= null;
    $nopostal = null;
    $nophone = null;
    $nodistance = null;
    // if value of variable is nothing assign something other than null
    if($first=="") {
        $nofirst = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($last==""){
        $nolast = '';
        $novalue ='';
    }
    if($email=="") {
        $noemail = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($address1=="") {
        $noaddress1 = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($address2=="") {
        $noaddress2 = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($city=="") {
        $nocity = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($state=="") {
        $nostate = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($postal=="") {
        $nopostal = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($phone=="") {
        $nophone = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($distance=="") {
        $nodistance = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if(isset($novalue)) {$confim = 'Please enter all values';}
        else {
        $insertsql = "INSERT INTO `runner`(`fname`, `lname`,`email`,`address1`,`address2`,`city`,`state`,`postalcode`, `phone`, `distance`) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$address1','$address2','$city','$state','$postal','$phone','$distance')";
        mysqli_query($lrconnect, $insertsql) or die ("Insert failed: ".mysql_error($lrconnect));
        $confirm = 'Thank you for registering!';
        }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <header><img src="images/eastersealsclevelogo.png" alt="Easter Seals Logo" width="445" height="300"</img> </header>
      <nav>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="signup.php" class="current">Run Sign-Up</a></li>
           <li><a href="refer.php" class="current">Refer-a-Friend</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
    <h1>Sign up for a event!</h1>
     <p>If you would like to join in any of the runs, then feel free to sign up using the form provided below.</p><br>
       <?php {echo $confirm;} ?>
       <form method="post" action="signup.php">
       <form name="signup" title="signup" id="signup">
       <table>
       <tr>
       <td><label for="first_name">First Name:</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" title="first name" ></td>
       <?php if(isset($nofirst)){echo"<span class='errormsg'> First name is required<br></span>";}?>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" title="last name" ></td>
       <?php if(isset($nolast)){echo"<span class='errormsg'> Last Name is required<br></span>";}?>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
       <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" title="email" ></td>
       <?php if(isset($noemail)){echo"<span class='errormsg'> Your Email is required<br></span>";}?>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td><label for="address1">Address 1:</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" title="address1" ></td>
       <?php if(isset($noaddress1)) {echo"<span class='errormsg'> Your Address is required<br></span>";}?>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td><label for="address2">Address 2:</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" title="address2"></td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td><label for="city">City:</label></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" title="city" value="Cleveland" ></td>
       <?php if(isset($nocity)){echo"<span class='errormsg'> Your City is required<br> </span>";}?>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td><label for="state">State:</label></td>
       <td>
    <select >
    <option value="AL" name="AL" title="alabama">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK" name="AK" title="alaska">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ" name="AZ" title="arizona">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR" name="AR" title="arkansas">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA" name="CA" title="california">California</option>
    <option value="CO" name="CO" title="colorado">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT" name="CT" title="connecticut">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE" name="DE" title="delware">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC" name="DC" title="district of columbia">District Of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL" name="FL" title="florida">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA" name="GA" title="georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI" name="HI" title="hawaii">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID" name="ID" title="idaho">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL" name="IL" title="illinois">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN" name="IN" title="indiana">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA" name="IA" title="iowa">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS" name="KA" title="kansas">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY" name="KY" title="kentucky">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA" name="LA" title="louisiana">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME" name="ME" title="maine">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD" name="MD" title="maryland">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA" name="MA" title="massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI" name="MI" title="michigan">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN" name="MN" title="minnesota">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS" name="MS" title="mississippi">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO" name="MO" title="missouri">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT" name="MT" title="montana">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE" name="NE" title="nebraska">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV" name="NV" title="nevada">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH" name="NH" title="new hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ" name="NJ" title="new jersey">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM" name="NM" title="new mexico">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY" name="NY" title="new york">New York</option>
    <option value="NC" name="NC" title="north carolina">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND" name="ND" title="north dakota">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH" name="OH" title="ohio" selected>Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK" name="OK" title="oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR" name="OR" title="oregon">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA" name="PA" title="pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI" name="RI" title="rhode island">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC" name="SC" title="south carolina">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD" name="SD" title="south dakota">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN" name="TN" title="tennessee">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX" name="TX" title="texas">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT" name="UT" title="utah">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT" name="VT" title="vermont">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA" name="VA" title="virginia">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA" name="WA" title="washington">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV" name="WV" title="west virginia">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI" name="WI" title="wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY" name="WY" title="wyoming">Wyoming</option>
</select></td>
    <?php if(isset($nostate)) {echo "<span class='errormsg'>Your state is required<br></span>";}?>
</tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label for="postal_code">Zip Code:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="postal_code" id="postal_code"  title="postal_code" pattern="[\d]{5}(-[\d]{4})" ></td>
    <?php if(isset($nopostal)) {echo "<span class='errormsg'> Your postal code is required<br></span>";}?>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label for="phone">Phone:</label></td>
    <td><input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" title="phone" ></td>
    <?php if(isset($nophone)) {echo "<span class='errormsg'> Your Phone number is required<br></span>";}?>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label for="distance">Distance:</label></td><br>
    <td><input type="radio" name="dist" value="1mile" id="dist" title="1mile" checked ><label>1 Mile</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="dist" value="5k" id="dist" title="5k"><label>5K</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="dist" value="10k" id="dist" title="10k"><label>10K</label></td>
    <?php if(isset($nodist)) {echo "<span class='errormsg'> You must choose a distance</span>";}?>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>  <input type="submit" name="submit_registration" id="submit_registration" title="submit" value="Submit Form"></td>
    <td>  <input type="button" name="cancel" id="cancel" title="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="location.href='index.html'"></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </form>

   </body>

</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to assigned name in all option tag like this.
`<option value="AL" name="AL" title="alabama">Alabama</option>`
Just assign a name in `<select name="dropdownname">` and get it in your request `$city = $_POST['dropdownname'];`

Answer (score 0):

i've just edited your PHP code because when i took a look at it i saw a lot of if statements. This doesnt solve your issue, but it makes your code more readable.

You should escape your variables when saving.

Did you turned error reporting on?

Hope my code helps you a bit on your way. For the input fields you can use the same variable shown below in the example. In your input field value you can use the code:

```
<input name="first_name" value="<?php echo isset($first_name) ? $first_name : '' ?>">
```

This is shorter for if else. If first_name is set then echo $first_name or else echo '';

```
<?php require_once('dbuser.php');?>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);


// if the submit button has been selected
if(isset($_POST['submit_registration'])) {
    //Those are the predefined fields, set in a array
    $fieldsArray = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'address1', 'address2', 'city', 'state', 'postal_code', 'phone', 'dist'];

    //The fields are always valid unless we get something else while looping
    $valid = true;
    //Loop through the fieldsArray
    foreach($fieldsArray as $key => $value){
        if(isset($_POST[$value])){
            //If $_POST with the value from the fieldsArray is SET, then create a variable called $first_name or $last_name, depends on the keys from
            // the fields array
            ${$value} = $_POST[$value];
        } else {
            //If the value is not set, then the validation is false
            $valid = false;
        }
    }

    //If false, then dont run the query
    if($valid == false)
    {
        $confim = 'Please enter all values';
    } else {
        $insertsql = "INSERT INTO `runner`(`fname`, `lname`,`email`,`address1`,`address2`,`city`,`state`,`postalcode`, `phone`, `distance`) VALUES ('".$first."', '".$last_name."', '$email', '$address1','$address2','$city','$state','$postal','$phone','$distance')";
        mysqli_query($lrconnect, $insertsql) or die ("Insert failed: ".mysql_error($lrconnect));
        $confirm = 'Thank you for registering!';
    }
}
```